# dynamically draw a line using DDA under openGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I am new to openGL, and I am learning DDA algorithm. Basically it is just use `glVertex2i(x, y)` to paint a lot of points and even to a line.

Now I want to achieve dynamic effect. So I add a `sleep(0.5)` statement to delay 0.5 second after I paint a point each time, but the result is not good. The result is just blank for a while and suddenly come out the whole line.

I also try the method below:

```
void delay(unsigned int mseconds)
{
    clock_t goal = mseconds + clock();
    while (goal > clock());
}
```

The result is same, the canvas will be blank for a while at first.

So is there any other way to delay?

---

Here is my code:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<time.h>

using namespace std;

void delay(unsigned int mseconds)
{
    clock_t goal = mseconds + clock();
    while (goal > clock());
}

float xs = 0.0;
float ys = 0.0;
float xe = 0.0;
float ye = 0.0;

void LineDDA(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1)
{
    float x = 0.0;
    float y = 0.0;
    float m = 0.0;
    float dx = x1 - x0;
    float dy = y1 - y0;
    if (dx != 0)
    {
        m = dy/dx;
        if (m <= 1 && m >= -1)
        {
            y = y0;
            for (x = x0; x <= x1; x++)
            {
                glVertex2i(x, int(y+0.5));
                delay(2000);
                y += m;
            }
        }
        if (m>1 || m<-1)
        {
            m = 1/m;
            x = x0;
            for (y=y0; y<=y1; y++)
            {
                glVertex2i(int(x+0.5), y);
                delay(2000);
                x += m;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        int x = x0;
        int y = 0;
        y = (y0 <= y1) ? y0 : y1;
        int d = fabs((double) (y0 - y1));
        while (d >= 0)
        {
            glVertex2i(x, y);
            delay(2000);
            y++;
            d--;
        }
    }
}

void lineSegment()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);

    // Make sure changes appear onscreen
    glutSwapBuffers();

    LineDDA(xs, ys, xe, ye);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB|GLUT_SINGLE);
    cout << "input the start and end（range is 0-500, 0-500）:";
    cin >> xs >> ys >> xe >> ye;
    glutInitWindowPosition(50, 100);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutCreateWindow("DDA Algothrim");
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    gluOrtho2D(0.0, 500, 0.0, 500.0);


    glutDisplayFunc(lineSegment);

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

And here is how I run it:

```
lzc@lzc-ubuntu:~/Workspace/Languages/openGL$ g++ dda.cpp -lglut -lGLU -lGL -lm
lzc@lzc-ubuntu:~/Workspace/Languages/openGL$ ./a.out 
input the start and end（range is 0-500, 0-500）:0 0 200 300
```

My g++ version is: `gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2)`

Comment: Do you have to call some swap-buffers function to display the frame?

Comment: @immibis I add a `glutSwapBuffers()` call before DDA function, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your intention is to draw the line as animation. To do so, you should use timer. Using GLUT, we have two ways to incorporate timer into the display code.

1. `glutIdleFunc` 
   This is straight forward: just give the display function as its argument, in your case, `lineSegment` 
    
   The limitation with this approach is that we cannot control the ticking frequency of the timer. If we do want to set our own ticking frequency, we need to use the second approach.
2. `glutTimerFunc` 
   It takes as input, the frequency to trigger each call back (in milliseconds) along with the call back function pointer. 
   In both approaches,  you need to modify your display function to increment the value on each tick; in your case, the index of the point to be drawn.